# What is the logic to find a missing number in a sequence?

Tags: java

I am trying to write a simple algorithm to identify the first missing real number in an `ArrayList` of integers. I am having difficulty writing the logic. Observe my code snippit:

```
// suppose sequence is a valid sorted ArrayList

int match = 0;
int first = sequence.get(0); // sets the first value in seq. to var
int size = sequence.size(); // sets the seq size to var
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    if (i != sequence.get(i) && i > first)
        match = i; // it is not in the sequence
}
System.out.println(match + " is not in the sequence.");
```

If the sequence is `4, 5, 8, 9` I'd expect `match` to be `6`. Instead I'm getting a `0`. Help?

Comment: For your example, would you want it to also match 7? Will the sequence always increment by 1?

Comment: Probably because `i` is just an int that goes 0,1,2,3. It never even reaches `4` so it can't possibly ever become `>` than any of the values in your sequence.

Comment: @PlasmaPower No and N/A. It just needs to find the first missing value and the sequence can be any sorted list of ints.

Comment: I hope you mean "missing int", because there is no "first" real number.  (What's the first real number after 0?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your `if` condition demands that `sequence.get(i)` be equal to `i`. Instead, it should be `first + i`, and the second part of the condition needs to be removed:

```
if ((first + i) != sequence.get(i)) {
    match = (first + i);
    break;
}
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/sQwTmK)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int max = -1;
for(int i=1; i<sequence.size(); i++) {
    if(sequence.get(i) > sequence.get(i - 1)) {
        match = i + 1;
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println(match + " is not in the sequence.");
```

Answer (score 0):

The a check would be something like `sequence.get(i+1) == sequence.get(i) + 1`. And if that fails you would return `sequence.get(i) + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import  java.util.Arrays;
import  java.util.List;
/**
   <P>{@code java FindMissingNumInSequence}</P>
 **/
public class FindMissingNumInSequence  {
   public static final void main(String[] ignored)  {
      List<Integer> ascUnqIntList = Arrays.asList(4, 5, 8, 9);

      int num = ascUnqIntList.get(0);  //Initialize to the first one
      for(int i : ascUnqIntList)  {
         if(num != i)  {
            System.out.println("First missing number in sequence: " + num);
            break;
         }
         System.out.println(i);
         num++;
      }
   }
}
```

Output:

```
[C:\java_code\]java FindMissingNumInSequence
4
5
First missing number in sequence: 6
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you in getting what you want assuming that array list is already sorted.

```
for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
{
    if (sequence.get(i+1) - sequence.get(i) > 1 ) {
        match = sequence.get(i) + 1; // it is not in the sequence
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FindMissingNumber {

public static void main(String args[]){
    int[] arr = {5,6,7,0,9};

    int start = arr[0];
    int length = arr.length;
    int total = 0;
    int missing = 0;
    if(start == 1){
        missing = ((length*(length+1))/2) - arrTotal(arr); 
    }else{
        total = ((arr[length-1]*(arr[length-1]+1))/2)-(((start-1)*start)/2);
        missing = total - arrTotal(arr);
    }
    System.out.println("Missing Number : "+missing);
}

private static int arrTotal(int[] arr){
    int total = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
        total += arr[i];
    }
    return  total;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MissingNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MissingNumber num=new MissingNumber();
        int[] numb={2,4,6,10,12,14,};
        num.solution(numb);

    }
    public int solution(int[] A) {

        int j=0;
        int k=0;
        int missingNum=0;
        int[] arrayInt=A;
        int diff=0;
        for(int i=0;i<arrayInt.length-2;i++)
        {
            j=arrayInt[i+1]- arrayInt[i];

            k=arrayInt[i+2]-arrayInt[i+1];
            if(j==k){
                 diff= k;
            }
            if(j!=k)
            {
                if(j!=diff)
                { 
                    missingNum=arrayInt[i]+diff;
                }
                else if(k!=diff){
                     missingNum=arrayInt[i+1]+diff;
                }


            }

        }  
        System.out.println("Missing number"+missingNum);
        return missingNum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation of how this code snippet answers the question?